# How to echo iframe in existing echo

Tags: php, iframe, echo

I want to **echo iframe ($test2)** in already existing **echo ($loop)** but my website doesn't load when I do so.

Where is the problem?

I think it has something to do with `echo` in the `echo` problem.

```html
<?php
function sac_getData($sac_lastID) {
 
 global $wpdb, $table_prefix, $sac_lastID, $sacGetChat;
 
 $loop = ''; 
 
 if (isset($_GET['sac_nonce_receive']) && wp_verify_nonce($_GET['sac_nonce_receive'], 'sac_nonce_receive')) {
  
  if ((isset($sacGetChat) && $sacGetChat === 'yes') && (!empty($sac_lastID) && is_numeric($sac_lastID))) {
   
   $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ". $table_prefix ."ajax_chat WHERE id > ". $sac_lastID ." ORDER BY id DESC", ARRAY_A);
   
   for ($row = 0; $row < 1; $row++) {
    
    if (isset($query[$row]) && !empty($query[$row]) && is_array($query[$row])) {
     
     $id   = isset($query[$row]['id'])   ? $query[$row]['id']   : '';
     $time = isset($query[$row]['time']) ? $query[$row]['time'] : '';
     $name = isset($query[$row]['name']) ? $query[$row]['name'] : '';
     $text = isset($query[$row]['text']) ? $query[$row]['text'] : '';
     $url  = isset($query[$row]['url'])  ? $query[$row]['url']  : '';
     
     $time = sac_time_since($time);
     
$user = get_user_by('slug', $name);
$X = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'description', true);     
$test2 = echo '<iframe width="100" height="40" src="https://X.com/'.$X.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>';     
    
     
     
$loop = $id .'---'. $test2 .'---'. $text .'---'. $time .' '. esc_html__('ago', 'X') .'---'. $url .'---';
     
    }
    
   }
   
  }
  
 }
 
 echo $loop;
 
}
add_action('init', 'sac_getData');
?>
```

I have tried this.

```html
<?php
function sac_getData($sac_lastID) {
 
 global $wpdb, $table_prefix, $sac_lastID, $sacGetChat;
 
 $loop = ''; 
 
 if (isset($_GET['sac_nonce_receive']) && wp_verify_nonce($_GET['sac_nonce_receive'], 'sac_nonce_receive')) {
  
  if ((isset($sacGetChat) && $sacGetChat === 'yes') && (!empty($sac_lastID) && is_numeric($sac_lastID))) {
   
   $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ". $table_prefix ."ajax_chat WHERE id > ". $sac_lastID ." ORDER BY id DESC", ARRAY_A);
   
   for ($row = 0; $row < 1; $row++) {
    
    if (isset($query[$row]) && !empty($query[$row]) && is_array($query[$row])) {
     
     $id   = isset($query[$row]['id'])   ? $query[$row]['id']   : '';
     $time = isset($query[$row]['time']) ? $query[$row]['time'] : '';
     $name = isset($query[$row]['name']) ? $query[$row]['name'] : '';
     $text = isset($query[$row]['text']) ? $query[$row]['text'] : '';
     $url  = isset($query[$row]['url'])  ? $query[$row]['url']  : '';
     
     $time = sac_time_since($time);
     
$user = get_user_by('slug', $name);
$test2 = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'description', true);     
  
     
     
$loop = $id .'---'. <?php echo '<iframe width="100" height="40" src="https://X.com/'.$test2.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>':?> .'---'. $text .'---'. $time .' '. esc_html__('ago', 'simple-ajax-chat') .'---'. $url .'---';
     
    }
    
   }
   
  }
  
 }
 
 echo $loop;
 
}
add_action('init', 'sac_getData');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have written:

```
$loop = $id .'---'. <?php echo '<iframe width="100" height="40" src="https://X.com/'.$test2.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>':?> .'---'. $text .'---'. $time .' '. esc_html__('ago', 'simple-ajax-chat') .'---'. $url .'---';
```

You're already in PHP at this point. Using another PHP tag is pointless. Also, not clear what you're trying to accomplish with ":?>"; the colon there is wrong.

Eliminating those issues and merging some strings that end up adjacent to each other as a result gives this:

```
$loop = $id .'---<iframe width="100" height="40" src="https://X.com/'.$test2.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>---'. $text .'---'. $time .' '. esc_html__('ago', 'simple-ajax-chat') .'---'. $url .'---';
```

Comment: Hi. This solution prints only text `<iframe width="100" height="40" src="https://X.com/'.$test2.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>` but not the actual iframe. The `$test2` value is shown correctly but as i sed iframe is printed as it is/text only.

Comment: Not clear what you mean. Exactly what does your resulting HTML look like when you use this code?

Comment: Like this in plain text so its not fetching/opening the iframe just prints the code as text. But $test2 result is printed correctly. <iframe width="100" height="40" src="https://X.com/'.$test2.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Comment: Is it literally putting `<iframe width="100" height="40" src="X.com/'.$test2.'" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>` in your HTML, or is it something like `<iframe width="100" height="40" src="X.com/abc" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>` if `$test2` were "abc"?